# Likelihood values from Sigmoid

Tags: probability, density-function, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression, log-likelihood

There are multiple doubts of mine associated around this theme:

- In MLE, we try to find the PDF parameters ($\theta$) which maximise the likelihood of the observed data ($L(\theta | data)$). To get likelihood for a given data point for $\theta = \theta_1$ we simply evaluate the PDF for that data point. Now, we know that probability at any one particular point of a PDF is $0$. What is the correct reasoning behind evaluating the PDF at $x=x_1$ for its likelihood?
- Clearly, the Sigmoid Function is not a PDF. But in the MLE estimates of Logistic Regression we see Sigmoid being used as if it is a PDF. Is my understanding correct ? If not, how to see it correctly? If yes, what is the reason behind it?
- This is related to the previous question. I have seen at multiple places that people take the Sigmoid to infer probability. However there is not any constraint put to ensure that sum of all those probabilities must be $1$. What is the correct explanation behind it?

Comment: The probability and the PDF are not the same unless one has a discrete distribution. The probability is the "mass" of the event, the PDF is its density

Comment: @rubikscube09, yes, that is true. I wanted to know what the reason behind evaluating the PDF at a given point and taking it as a likelihood mean. At the same time we know that the probability of occurrence of that point from the PDF to be 0. I added this info just to draw analogy.

Comment: Got it. Even though PDF doesn't mean probability, the maximum of the PDF is the mode of the distribution. If you think of discrete distributions, with all bins equal size, then the most probable is the highest bin. Taking limit of bins to be smaller and smaller, which gives you the PDF generalizes this idea, only this time it is maximum of density function.

Answer (score 1):

- A maximum likelihood estimator is a set of parameters maximizing the likelihood function, just one way to formulate things. The maximum will occur at a stationary point or at a boundary point.
- As far as a sigmoid function (between 0 and 1) being treated as a distribution function, that's purely an analytical ansatz. There might be cases where a model justifies statistical interpretation of logit or probit regression.